# Turning Java object class into Swift class

Tags: ios, swift, object

So I'm learning how to make my Android apps into an iOS app. I've gotten pretty far though I'm having an issue when it comes creating the object. In my android app I read in a csv file and create a FireworkList object that contains info. Here is the code from my Android app:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FireworksList{



private ArrayList<Integer> _category = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> _name = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> _shotCount = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> _price = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> _description = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> _videoUrl = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Integer> _imageResourceNumber = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Boolean> _favorite = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Boolean> _special = new ArrayList<>();
private Integer _specialCategoryNumer =15;
private Integer _nextId;




public FireworksList() {
    _nextId=0;
}




public ArrayList<Integer> get_category() {
    return _category;
}

public ArrayList<String> get_name() {
    return _name;
}

public ArrayList<String> get_shotCount() {
    return _shotCount;
}

public ArrayList<String> get_price() {
    return _price;
}

public ArrayList<String> get_description() {
    return _description;
}

public ArrayList<String> get_videoUrl() {
    return _videoUrl;
}

public ArrayList<Integer> get_imageResourceNumber() {
    return _imageResourceNumber;
}

public ArrayList<Boolean> get_favorite() {
    return _favorite;
}

public void set_favorite(int index, Boolean bool) {
    _favorite.set(index,bool);
}

public ArrayList<Boolean> get_special(){return _special;}









public void Add(int cat, String name, String shot, String price, String description, String video, int image, Boolean fav, Boolean special){
    _category.add(_nextId,cat);
    _name.add(_nextId,name);
    _shotCount.add(_nextId,shot);
    _price.add(_nextId,price);
    _description.add(_nextId,description);
    _videoUrl.add(_nextId,video);
    _imageResourceNumber.add(_nextId,image);
    _favorite.add(_nextId,fav);
    _special.add(_nextId,special);
    _nextId++;

}


public int Count(){
    return _nextId;
}

public FireworksList CategorySort(int position){
    FireworksList fireworksListTemp = new FireworksList();

    for(int i=0; i<_nextId;i++){
        if(position==0){
            fireworksListTemp.Add(_category.get(i),_name.get(i),_shotCount.get(i),_price.get(i),_description.get(i),_videoUrl.get(i),_imageResourceNumber.get(i),_favorite.get(i),_special.get(i));
        }

        else if(position==_category.get(i)){
            fireworksListTemp.Add(_category.get(i),_name.get(i),_shotCount.get(i),_price.get(i),_description.get(i),_videoUrl.get(i),_imageResourceNumber.get(i),_favorite.get(i),_special.get(i));

        }
        else if(position==_specialCategoryNumer&&_special.get(i)==true){
            fireworksListTemp.Add(_category.get(i),_name.get(i),_shotCount.get(i),_price.get(i),_description.get(i),_videoUrl.get(i),_imageResourceNumber.get(i),_favorite.get(i),_special.get(i));
        }
    }

    return fireworksListTemp;
}


public FireworksList FavoriteSort(){
    FireworksList fireworksListTemp = new FireworksList();
    for(int i = 0; i<_nextId;i++){
        if(_favorite.get(i)==true){
            fireworksListTemp.Add(_category.get(i),_name.get(i),_shotCount.get(i),_price.get(i),_description.get(i),_videoUrl.get(i),_imageResourceNumber.get(i),_favorite.get(i),_special.get(i));
        }
    }
    return  fireworksListTemp;
}

public int FindIndex(String name, FireworksList fireworksList){
    int found=0;
    for(int j=0;j<fireworksList.Count();j++){
        if(fireworksList.get_name().get(j).equals(name)){
            found=j;
        }
    }
    return found;
}



}
```

I've started rewriting my code yet I ran into an issue when it came to creating a new Firework list then appending to it with what is needed in the categorySort function. Here is my modified code so far:

```
class FireworkList {



var _category = [Int]()
var _name = [String]()
var _shotCount = [String]()
var _price = [String]()
var _description = [String]()
var _videioUrl = [String]()
var _imageResourceNumber = [Int]()
var _favorite = [Bool]()
var _special = [Bool]()
private var _specialCategoryNumber : Int = 15
private var _nextId : Int = 0


func FireworksList(){_nextId = 0}
func get_category() -> Array<Int>{return _category}
func get_name() -> Array<String>{return _name}
func get_shotCount() -> Array<String>{return _shotCount}
func get_price() -> Array<String>{return _price}
func get_discription() -> Array<String>{return _description}
func get_videoUrl() -> Array<String>{return _videioUrl}
func get_imageResourceNumber() -> Array<Int>{return _imageResourceNumber}
func get_favorite() -> Array<Bool>{return _favorite}
func get_special() -> Array<Bool>{return _special}
func set_favorite(index : Int, bool : Bool){_favorite[index] = bool}



func add(cat : Int, name : String, shot : String, price : String, description : String, video : String, image : Int, fav : Bool, special : Bool){
    _category.insert(cat, at: _nextId)
    _name.insert(name, at: _nextId)
    _shotCount.insert(shot, at: _nextId)
    _price.insert(price, at: _nextId)
    _description.insert(description, at: _nextId)
    _videioUrl.insert(video, at: _nextId)
    _favorite.insert(fav, at: _nextId)
    _special.insert(special, at: _nextId)
    _nextId+=1
}


func Count()->Int{return _nextId}



func CategorySort(position : Int)-> [FireworkList]{
   var fireworkListTemp = [FireworkList]()

    for i in 0..._nextId{
        if(position == 0){
            fireworkListTemp.append(FireworkList())
        }
    }

    return fireworkListTemp
}
}
```

I'm thankful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue here is that your java class is poorly designed and you are taking this design with you when writing it in swift. Rather than having a bunch of properties that are collections you should create a struct for those properties and have one array with the struct. (I didn't include all properties to keep the code shorter).

```
struct Firework {
    var category: Int
    var name: String
    var shotCount: String
    var price: String
    var special: Bool
}
```

and then declare it in the main class

```
class FireworkList {
    private var fireworks = [Firework]()
```

Below is the class with the `add`, `count` and `categorySort` functions to show some examples of how to use this struct. As you can see this means much less code. I also taken the liberty to rename properties and functions to follow recommended swift naming practices.

For the `categorySort` I have made use of the high order function `filter` to collect the correct items. If you are going to work with swift I would recommend you learn more about it and the other high order functions like `sort`, `map` etc.

Also worth mentioning to someone coming from java is that we don't use get/set methods to the same extent in swift. We most access the property directly like `let x = myObject.someValue` or `myObject.someValue = 10`

```
class FireworkList {
    var fireworks = [Firework]()

    private let specialCategoryNumber = 15

    func add(cat : Int, name : String, shot : String, price : String, special: Bool) {
        self.fireworks.append(Firework(category: cat, name: name, shotCount: shot, price: price, special: special))
    }

    func count() -> Int { return fireworks.count }

    func categorySort(position : Int) -> [Firework] {            
        switch position {
        case 0:
            return self.fireworks
        case specialCategoryNumber:
            return self.fireworks.filter { $0.category == specialCategoryNumber && $0.special}
        default:
            return self.fireworks.filter {$0.category == position}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. There is always something to learn and that's what make coding fun and a pain.lol

Comment: @TonyKieffaber Great, don't forget to upvote and mark as accepted if you find the answer useful.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it:

```
public class FireworksList {
    private var _category = [Int]()
    private var _name = [String]()
    private var _shotCount = [String]()
    private var _price = [String]()
    private var _description = [String]()
    private var _videoURL = [String]()
    private var _imageResourceNumber = [Int]()
    public var favorite = [Bool]()
    private var _special = [Bool]()

    private let specialCategoryNumber = 15
    private var nextId = 0

    public var category: [Int] {
        get {
            return _category
        }
    }

    public var name: [String] {
        get {
            return _name
        }
    }

    public var shotCount: [String] {
        get {
            return _shotCount
        }
    }

    public var price: [String] {
        get {
            return _price
        }
    }

    public var description: [String] {
        get {
            return _description
        }
    }

    public var videoURL: [String] {
        get {
            return _videoURL
        }
    }

    public var imageResourceNumber: [Int] {
        get {
            return _imageResourceNumber
        }
    }

    public var special: [Bool] {
        get {
            return _special
        }
    }

    public var count: Int {
        get {
            return nextId
        }
    }


    public func add( cat: Int, name: String, shot: String, price: String, description: String, video: String, image: Int, fav: Bool, special: Bool) {
        self._category.append(cat)
        self._name.append(name)
        self._shotCount.append(shot)
        self._price.append(price)
        self._description.append(description)
        self._videoURL.append(video)
        self._imageResourceNumber.append(image)
        self.favorite.append(fav)
        self._special.append(special)
        nextId += 1
    }

    public func categorySort(at position: Int) -> FireworksList {
        let tmp = FireworksList()

        for i in 0...nextId {
            if position == 0 || position == category[i] ||
                (position == specialCategoryNumber && special[i] == true) {
                tmp.add(cat: category[i], name: name[i], shot: shotCount[i], price: price[i], description: description[i], video: videoURL[i], image: imageResourceNumber[i], fav: favorite[i], special: special[i])
            }
        }

        return tmp
    }
    public func favouriteSort() -> FireworksList {
        let tmp = FireworksList()
        for i in 0...nextId {
            if favorite[i] {
                tmp.add(cat: category[i], name: name[i], shot: shotCount[i], price: price[i], description: description[i], video: videoURL[i], image: imageResourceNumber[i], fav: favorite[i], special: special[i])
            }
        }

        return tmp
    }

    // I'm putting this function as static as it isn't directly related to any particular instance of FireworksList at any point of time.
    public static func findIndex(name: String, fireworksList: FireworksList) -> Int {
        var found = 0

        for j in 0...fireworksList.count {
            if fireworksList.name[j] == name {
                found = j
            }
        }

        return found
    }



}
```

My code simply almost directly follows your Java code.

This is my first time trying to contribute in Stack Overflow, and I hope this can be helpful to you.